# Specifying which field failed validation

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I'm using an If statement to validate whether input fields meet certain criteria. In the case validation fails, an alert will appear and the input border turns red.

How can I ensure that only the input field that failed validation turns red? I considered separating them into If and Else, however, this will obviously do one or the other in the case both fail. This leads me to believe that If is not best suited here, or that there could be a way to specify inside the first If block.

> !
> if (
> document.getElementById("name").value.length > "30" ||
> document.getElementById("commentText").value.length > "100"
> ) {
> document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
> alert("Name must have fewer than 30 characters");
> e.preventDefault();
> } else {....

I updated the code as below, however, the first if statement which checks if both fields are invalid is not being executed... I'm not sure why?

Updated Code:

```
if (
    document.getElementById("name").value.length > 30 &&
    document.getElementById("commentText").value.length > 100
  ) {
    document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
    document.getElementById("commentName").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert(
      "Name must have fewer than 30 characters, and comment fewer than 100 characters"
    );
    event.preventDefault();
    // document.getElementById("form").reset()
  } else if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 30) {
    document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Name must have fewer than 30 characters");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (document.getElementById("commentText").value.length > 100) {
    document.getElementById("commentText").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Comment must have fewer than 100 characters");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not two separate `if` blocks?  For example:

```
let isValid = true;
let errors = "";

if (document.getElementById("name").value.length > 30) {
  isValid = false;
  document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
  errors += "Name must have fewer than 30 characters. ";
}
if (document.getElementById("commentText").value.length > 100) {
  isValid = false;
  document.getElementById("commentText").style.border = "2px solid red";
  errors += "Comment must have fewer than 100 characters. ";
}

if (!isValid) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(errors);
} else {
  //...
}
```

Basically check each field and build up the validation errors, then respond to the overall failed validation at the end of those checks.

Comment: I followed this, and added one for whether both fields are invalid, but this isn't working. I updated the code in the original question.

Comment: @amputator: Define "isn't working".  In what way does this fail?  The updated question isn't using this answer, so it's not clear what issue you're having with this answer.  (The updated code in the question also has a lot of repetition.  I highly recommend the approach shown here.)

Comment: My bad - I meant I updated to using multiple if statements. The first if block doesn't run even if both inputs are invalid. From what I understand, the code here only displays an error if one or the other is invalid, not both.

I'll give this particular method a go, too.

Comment: Update - did it this way and it does account for both being invalid! (of course, you already knew this). I added a reset of the border color above this code to ensure only the invalid field is red. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

data type return by `.length` is `number` not a `string`.
Also change the comparison sign.

```
if (
    document.getElementById("name").value.length < 30 ||
    document.getElementById("commentText").value.length < 100
  ) {
    document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Name must have fewer than 30 characters");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
else{
   //your stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: True, though JavaScript will automatically coerce the string values to numbers for the comparison.  But it's still always a good idea to keep the data types consistent like this, as relying on type coercion often leads to bugs.

Comment: Hadn't noticed I was doing that - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Why change the comparison logic?

Comment: `alert("Name must have fewer than 30 characters");` this was specificed

Comment: @ShreyBhangale: So, by this logic, you're checking if something **does** have fewer than 30 characters, and when it **does** you still show the user an error saying that it needs to?

Comment: Yeah! because word **fewer**, I thought that less than sign should be there to work. If it is greater than given values, it will work after that length exceeds **30**

Comment: @ShreyBhangale: Consider a scenario... The user enters 20 characters.  Your comparison is `true` because `20 < 30`.  Your code presents the user with an error saying *"Name must have fewer than 30 characters"*.  Why should the user get this error when they entered 20 characters?  The OP likely only wants to display the errors when the input **fails** validation, not when it **passes** validation.

Answer (score 0):

I would have another if field for commentText id

```
if (
    document.getElementById("name").value.length > 30
  ) {
    document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Name must have fewer than 30 characters");
    e.preventDefault();
  } 
if (
    document.getElementById("commentText").value.length > 100
  ) {
    document.getElementById("commentText").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Comment must have fewer than 100 characters");
    e.preventDefault();
  }else {....
```

Comment: I followed this, and added one for whether both fields are invalid, but this isn't working. I updated the code in the original question.